# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Live Usb Freeze

Tags: live-usb, asus

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my asus laptop, but the screen freezes when loading Live image. I made the bootable usb using Rufus, GPT partition for UEFI.
[image of error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg0yG.jpg)

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Comment: Please tell us about the computer and of the graphics chip/card: Brand name and model of both.

Comment: It's an asus vivobook x412da with amd ryzen 5 3500u and Radeon vega graphics

Comment: Try with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` to help get graphics with the graphics chip.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome :-) After you have installed Ubuntu you can check if there is a suitable proprietary driver (maybe, maybe not).

Comment: After successful installation Ubuntu is not booting. I am getting a black screen with error messages and a blinking cursor.

Comment: I think you need `nomodeset` also in the installed system.

Comment: Worked again. Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to make it persistent (so that `nomodeset` will be used after rebooting)?

Comment: I have to edit the script for grub I think

Comment: Yes, edit `/etc/default/grub`, the value of 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` (put it after 'quiet splash'), and run `sudo update-grub`